# Export vector data from ngspice

Tags: ngspice

Is it possible to export vector values or other data from ngspice to a file?

It would be nice to use the data in other programs such as octave or gnplot for prettier plots.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 17.5.85 from the user manual: http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice26-manual.pdf

`wrdata <file> <vector>`